# Verifying the Stokes' Theorem

Tags: surfaces, stokes-theorem

Given
$$z=10-x^2-y^2,\quad1\leq z\leq9,$$
I have to verify the Stokes' Theorem with
$$F(x,y,z)=(3z,4x,2y)$$

Since $\nabla\times F=(2,3,4)$ and as we can parametrize the surface as follows
$$\sigma(r,\theta)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,10-r^2)$$
with $1\leq r\leq 3,0\leq\theta\leq2\pi$, then
$$\sigma_{r}=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta,-2r),\qquad\sigma_{\theta}=(-r\sin\theta,r\cos\theta,0)$$
So,
$$\sigma_{r}\times\sigma_{\theta}=(2r^2\cos\theta,2r^2\sin\theta,r)$$
Therefore,
$$\iint_{R}\nabla\times FdS=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{1}^{3}(2,3,4)(2r^2\cos\theta,2r^2\sin\theta,r)drd\theta=32\pi$$

On the other hand, the boundary of the surface has two curves
$$\gamma_{1}(t)=(\cos(t),\sin(t),1)$$
and
$$\gamma_{2}(t)=(\cos(t),\sin(t),9)$$
for $0\leq t\leq2\pi$. Then $\gamma=\gamma_{2}\cup\gamma_{1}$, i.e.,
$$\int_{\gamma}Fdr=\int_{\gamma_{2}}Fdr-\int_{\gamma_{1}}Fdr$$
I know $\gamma_{1}'(t)=\gamma_{2}(t)=(-\sin(t),\cos(t),0)$. Therefore,
$$\int_{\gamma_{1}}Fdr=\int_{0}^{2\pi}(3,4\cos(t),2\sin(t))(-\sin(t),\cos(t),0)dt=4\pi$$
Also,
$$\int_{\gamma_{2}}Fdr=\int_{0}^{2\pi}(27,4\cos(t),2\sin(t))(-\sin(t),\cos(t),0)dt=4\pi$$
Hence,
$$\int_{\gamma}Fdr=4\pi-4\pi=0\neq32\pi$$
So, Stokes' Theorem is not verified. Why? What is wrong?

Comment: Your parametrization of $\gamma_2$ is a circle of radius $1$, it should be of radius $3$.

Comment: You didn't change the radius. It should be $(3\cos t, 3\sin t, 1)$.

Comment: @jjagmath $(\cos t,\sin t,3)$ is not the same?

Comment: Of course not. One is a circle of radius $1$ on the plane $z=3$, the other is a circle of radius $3$ on the plane $z=1$.

Comment: And you can see easily see that the point $(\cos t, \sin t, 3)$ is not on the surface: $10-x^2-y^2 = 10 - \sin^2 t - \cos^2 t = 10-1=9\ne 3 = z$.

Comment: @jjagmath I appreciate your help. It worked now.